# How to compute NPV of Latin American swap CLP-TNA (chilean) using quantlib?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, swaps, quantlib, overnight-index

I am trying to value the Latin Americans swaps. But CLP-TNA valuation is far off from the actual valuation. Please suggest, what I am missing in below methodology to compute NPV.

```
# construct discount curve and libor curve
risk_free_rate = 0.01
libor_rate = 0.02
day_count = ql.Actual360()

discount_curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
     ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, risk_free_rate, day_count)
)

  libor_curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
  ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, libor_rate, day_count)
)
# CLP index
 CLP_index = ql.OvernightIndex('CLP', 0, ql.CLPCurrency(), ql.WeekendsOnly(), ql.Actual360())

 calendar = ql.WeekendsOnly()
settle_date = calendar.advance(calculation_date, 5, ql.Days)
maturity_date = calendar.advance(settle_date, 10, ql.Years)


  fixed_schedule = ql.Schedule(settle_date, maturity_date, 
                     fixed_leg_tenor, calendar,
                     ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                     ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)

  float_schedule = ql.Schedule (settle_date, maturity_date, 
                      float_leg_tenor, calendar,
                      ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                      ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)

  notional = 10000000
 fixed_rate = 0.025
fixed_leg_daycount = ql.Actual360()
float_spread = 0.004
 float_leg_daycount = ql.Actual360()

 ir_swap = ql.VanillaSwap(ql.VanillaSwap.Payer, notional, fixed_schedule, 
       fixed_rate, fixed_leg_daycount, float_schedule,
       libor3M_index, float_spread, float_leg_daycount )

 swap_engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(discount_curve)
 ir_swap.setPricingEngine(swap_engine)
```

Comment: I think it would be a useful exercise for someone to add to QL distro examples of pricing [Chile Cámara swap](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37702), [Brazil CDI](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/65559), Colombia TRM, etc.

Comment: By "actual valuation" do you mean the actual market value?  You'll need proper interest-rate curves to get that right.

Comment: Thanks @Luigi Ballabio. By Actual valuation means, am comparing the values with bloomberg valuation. In the post, I mentioned the curve construction using 'ql.overnightindex'.  My question is, if CLP follows the same method 'Plain vanilla swap' methodology for valuation or there is different method for CLP.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri Vulis. Yes. It will be useful, to see some examples of the latin americas indexes valuations.

Comment: If it pays an overnight index (compounded over the life of the coupon, I guess?) you probably want to use `ql.OvernightIndexedSwap`.  But my point on the curves was that you're using a 2% flat curve to forecast the index and a 1% flat curve to discount (the two `FlatForward` instances).  Bloomberg probably uses real market curves to calculate its prices.

Comment: I tried using 'swap = ql.OvernightIndexedSwap(ql.OvernightIndexedSwap.Receiver, [notional], fixedSchedule, fixedRate, ql.Actual360(), ql.WeekendsOnly(), CLP_index)' but I am getting error as 'TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_OvernightIndexedSwap'.'

Comment: @LuigiBallabio. Request you to provide the short code to value CLP vanilla swap. Your example will surely help in my work.

Comment: @LuigiBallabio. Are we connecting again to discuss the problem ? or you can throw some  light on CLP problem

Comment: I will when I get some time — as a suggestion, it would be helpful if you edited the question and describe what's special about CLP-TNA swaps.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that might point you in the right direction.
As Luigi said the comments, you can't really expect to arrive at comparable values if you are just using flat curves.

So the first step would be to build a curve comparable to Bloomberg.
I don't really have any experience with CLP buy looking at the info on BBG it looks like these swap are zero coupon until 18M and pay semi after that.

```
import QuantLib as ql
today = ql.Date(25,6,2021)
calendar = ql.WeekendsOnly()
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today
spot = calendar.advance(today, 2, ql.Days)
dayCount = ql.Actual360()

cop_ois_quotes = [
    ('3M', 0.780),
    ('6M', 1.140),
    ('9M', 1.435),
    ('12M', 1.770),
    ('18M', 2.145),
    ('2Y',  2.430),
    ('3Y',  2.745),
    ('4Y',  3.01),
    ('5Y',  3.28),
    ('6Y',  3.53),
    ('7Y',  3.715),
    ('8Y',  3.835),
    ('9Y',  3.93),
    ('10Y', 4.055),
    ('15Y', 4.365),
    ('20Y', 4.465),
]

helpers = []
clp_ois_yts = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()

index = ql.OvernightIndex('CLICP', 0, ql.CLPCurrency(), ql.WeekendsOnly(), dayCount, clp_ois_yts)
for tenor, value in cop_ois_quotes:
    value /= 100
    quote = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(value))
    period = ql.Period(tenor)
    paymentFrequency = ql.Semiannual if period.units() > 2 else ql.Once
    helper = ql.OISRateHelper(2, period, quote, index, paymentFrequency=paymentFrequency)
    helpers.append(helper)
clp_ois_crv = ql.PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount(spot, helpers, ql.ActualActual())
clp_ois_crv.enableExtrapolation()
clp_ois_yts.linkTo(clp_ois_crv)
```

You can then test your curve by pricing some swaps. Here I'm pricing the input instruments so it is expected to yield the same results but you can play around with other dates.

```
swapType = ql.OvernightIndexedSwap.Payer
nominal = 100

engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(clp_ois_yts)

for tenor, value in cop_ois_quotes:
    value /= 100
    maturity = calendar.advance(spot, ql.Period(tenor))
    freq = '18M' if ql.Period(tenor).units() == 2 else '6M'
    schedule = ql.MakeSchedule(spot, maturity, ql.Period(freq), calendar=calendar)
    ois_swap = ql.OvernightIndexedSwap(swapType, nominal, schedule, 0.0, dayCount, index)
    ois_swap.setPricingEngine(engine)
    print(f"{tenor}: {ois_swap.fairRate()*100:.4f}, {value*100:.4f}")
```

3M: 0.7800, 0.7800
6M: 1.1400, 1.1400
9M: 1.4350, 1.4350
12M: 1.7700, 1.7700
18M: 2.1450, 2.1450
2Y: 2.4300, 2.4300
3Y: 2.7479, 2.7450
4Y: 3.0100, 3.0100
5Y: 3.2800, 3.2800
6Y: 3.5300, 3.5300
7Y: 3.7150, 3.7150
8Y: 3.8350, 3.8350
9Y: 3.9312, 3.9300
10Y: 4.0550, 4.0550
15Y: 4.3650, 4.3650
20Y: 4.4651, 4.4650

Comment: Can you help me on my post https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69024/quantlib-valuation-of-inflation-swaps-of-gbp-rpi-using-quantlib-python

Comment: @ David Duarte, Can you look into my aforesaid post in the comment section? That will really help.