# Quantlib : Valuation of inflation swaps of EUR-RPI using quantlib python?

Tags: programming, swaps, quantlib, inflation

Below is the sample code to compute the inflation swaps. I have referred the Quantlib cookbook to get the flavor of Inflation swaps. But I feel that the term structure and final NPV is not accurate and also missing something. If anyone can look into the steps and provide the final NPV value of any hypothetical swap could be very useful.

```
import QuantLib as ql
import datetime
import pandas as pd

valuation_date = ql.Date(14, 5, 2021)
ql.Settings.instance().setEvaluationDate(valuation_date)
# sample par rate of eonia
#eonia_par_rates =  pd.read_csv('eonia.csv')
data = [['EONIA', 2022-5-14 ,2022-5-18,'1Y',-0.487185945], 
    ['EONIA', 2022-5-14 ,2023-5-18,'2Y',-0.47487549]]
eonia_par_rates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = 
    ['Curve','last_update','maturity','tenor','mid_yield'])

index = ql.Eonia()
helpers = []
for idx, row in eonia_par_rates.iterrows():
    rate = row["mid_yield"] / 100
    tenor = row.tenor
if tenor == "1D":
    print('1D')
    #helpers.append(ql.DepositRateHelper(rate, index))
else:
    helpers.append(
        ql.OISRateHelper(
        0, ql.Period(tenor), ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate)), index
    )
)
 ois = ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, ql.TARGET(), helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())
ois.enableExtrapolation()
observationLag = ql.Period("3M")
dc = ql.ActualActual()
frequency = ql.Monthly
cal = ql.UnitedKingdom()
bdc = ql.ModifiedFollowing
inflationIndex = ql.EUHICP(True)
# sample inflation rates of EUR-RPI
#infl_data = pd.read_csv('inflation_rates.csv')
data_2 = [[1.377, '1Y', 2022-5-14], 
    [1.311, '2Y',   2023-5-14]]
infl_data = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns = ['px_last', 'tenor_two,','maturity'])
infl_data['maturity'] = pd.to_datetime(infl_data['maturity'], format="%Y-%m-%d")


inflationRateHelpers = []
for idx, row in infl_data.iterrows():
    maturity = ql.Date().from_date(row.maturity)
    quote = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(row.px_last / 100.0))
    helper = ql.ZeroCouponInflationSwapHelper(
  quote,
  observationLag,
  maturity,
   cal,
   bdc,
   dc,
 inflationIndex
  )
 inflationRateHelpers.append(helper)
 baseZeroRate = infl_data.iloc[0].px_last / 100

 inflationCurve =ql.PiecewiseZeroInflation(          
                      valuation_date, 
                      cal, 
                      dc, 
                      observationLag, 
                      frequency, 
                      inflationIndex.interpolated(), 
                      baseZeroRate,
                      ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ois), 
                      inflationRateHelpers, 
                      1.0e-12, #error
                      ql.Linear())

inflationCurve.enableExtrapolation()

discountYTS = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
inflationYTS = ql.RelinkableZeroInflationTermStructureHandle()
discountYTS.linkTo(ois)
inflationYTS.linkTo(inflationCurve)
# sample historical rates of EUHICP
#rpi = pd.read_csv('historical_rates.csv')
data_3 = [[1982-1-1, 7889.25], 
    [1982-1-4, 7894.3]]
rpi = pd.DataFrame(data_3, columns = ['index', 'PX_LAST'])
rpi = rpi.set_index('index')

 inflationIndex = ql.EUHICP(True, inflationYTS)
rpi.index = pd.to_datetime(rpi.index)
for idx, row in rpi.iterrows():
    fixing_date = ql.Date().from_date(idx)
    inflationIndex.addFixing(fixing_date, row.PX_LAST, True)
```

## swap computation

```
notional = 1e6
startDate = ql.Date(26, 1, 2006)
endDate = ql.Date(26, 1, 2055)
fixedRate = 0.032
swapType = ql.ZeroCouponInflationSwap.Payer
 swap = ql.ZeroCouponInflationSwap(
        swapType,
      notional,
     startDate,
     endDate,
      cal,
     ql.ModifiedFollowing,
      dc,
      fixedRate,
     inflationIndex,
      observationLag,
    )
  swapEngine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(discountYTS)
  swap.setPricingEngine(swapEngine)


npv = swap.NPV()
```

Comment: Hi. Can anyone reply on my post. That will really help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Still waiting for anyone to reply. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. I just tried to run your code and I got an error. Can you please provide a minimal working example? That would make it much easier to help you

Comment: @mmencke thanks for your reply. As requested I have edited my post. If you find errors in rates or fixings,  please add some hypothetical rates.  The format of the rate data frame is defined in the code. Please text me if you need more information.

Comment: Hi again. I have tried to run the adjusted code using a csv with EUHICP fixings and I still get an error: "2nd leg: all instruments expired". I'll have a look at it later today to figure out where the error comes from

Comment: @mmencke Thank you. I will surely wait for your reply.

Comment: I had a wrong date format in some of the input. I have now taken a look at it. One thing I noticed was how sensitive the floating leg is to the baseRate. Setting baseRate = 1.377%, gives inflationCurve.zeroRate(endDate)=0.265%, while setting baseRate = 1.311% gives inflationCurve.zeroRate(endDate)=1.311%. I am not sure why the zero rate change with the base rate, but given thes rates I can get fairly close to the inflation leg in both cases: (swap.inflationLeg())[0].amount(). I thus think that *if* there is an issue with the NPV calculation it is with the calculation of the zero rate

Comment: @mmencke Thanks for your reply. I was eagerly waiting on this one. That means zero rates should be the same as base rates? Do you think that all the steps and helpers are correct and there is an issue with the zero rate ? Can you share your final code to compare with mine ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132400/discussion-between-mmencke-and-robin).

Comment: @mmencke Do you have any suggestions on this post (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69846/quantlib-how-to-use-maturities-in-place-of-tenors-in-ois-rate-helpers-quantlib)